# How to provide partial confidentiality and full integrity for a protocol message?

Tags: encryption, hmac, cbc

I want to provide confidentiality and integrity for a protocol. I don't want to encrypt the entire protocol message. I do not want to encrypt the header and timestamp of the protocol message, but I want to have the integrity for the entire protocol message. Thus I do the following:

```
1- encrypt the message except for the header and timestamp by using CBC.
2- digest the entire message (header, timestamp and encrypted message) by using HMAC.
```

Is that good practice? if No, what is the best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that good practice?

If you use different and independent keys for HMAC and CBC and include the IV for CBC in the digest and use different key-pairs for both transmission directions, then yes, this is a good encryption scheme.

> what is the best practice?

As [Eugene Styer noted in their answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/61497/23623) it is best practice to use ready-made [*authenticated encryption with associated data*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) (AEAD) like AES-GCM, AES-EAX, AES-CCM, ChaCha20-Poly1305, ... for this which allows you to input your header as "associated data" and your message as plaintext. Your environment may already provide a NaCl / Sodium library [which includes AEAD functionality](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/secret-key_cryptography/aead.html).

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you want is a [authenticated encryption with associated data (AEAD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) encryption scheme, of which there are several already available in various libraries.  So just see what is available on your system and use one of them.